# Show that $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan(kx)}{k^2}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan(kx)}{k^2}$$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

By the Weierstrass' test, I can show that $f(x)$ is uniformly convergent and thus continuous. By checking that $f'(x)$ is uniformly convergent if $x \neq 0$, I also know that it's differentiable at those points.

So, $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, but not differentiable. How do I prove that it's not differentiable?

---

$f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3x^2+k}$ and by setting $x=0$, I get
$$f'(0) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k},$$ which I know diverges. But this is not enough to show that it's not differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: Showing that $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ blows up is not sufficient, you need to show that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \sum_k \frac{\arctan(kh)}{k^2}$ doesn't converge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan kh}{k^2h}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2h}\int^{kh}_0 \frac{du}{1+u^2}\\&\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{1+k^2h^2}\\&\ge\sum_{k\le \frac 1 h} \frac{1}{2k}=\frac 12 H_{\lfloor \frac 1 h\rfloor}\to \infty
\end{align*}$$ as $h\to 0^+$ where $H_n = 1+\frac 1 2+\cdots +\frac 1 n$.

Comment: Two of your lines are identical.

Comment: @Ian Fixed now, thank you!

Comment: @Simon How did you go from second line to third line?

Comment: Noting that $u^2\le k^2h^2$, we get $\int_0^{kh} \frac1{1+u^2}du\ge \int_0^{kh} \frac1{1+k^2h^2}du=\frac{kh}{1+k^2h^2}.$ Hopefully, is it clear now?

Comment: @Simon Still a bit confused. Understand the rest, but I'm getting stuck at why and how you arrived at $u^2 \leq k^2h^2$?

Comment: @wednesdaymiko $u^2 \leq k^2 h^2$ just falls out from the limits of integration.

Comment: Update for future or anyone interested, a slight tweak. As $arctan(x) > \frac{x}{1+x^2}$, you directly end up with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ bounded from below, thus not differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

$f$ is defined as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\arctan(kx)}{k^2}\tag1
$$
For $0\lt x\le1$, the Mean Value Theorem says that there is a $h\in(0,x)$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x
&=f'(h)\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k\left(1+k^2h^2\right)}\tag{2b}\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor1/h\rfloor}\frac1{2k}\tag{2c}\\
&\ge\frac12\log(1/h)\tag{2d}\\
&\ge\frac12\log(1/x)\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ Mean Value Theorem
$\text{(2b):}$ differentiate term by term
$\text{(2c):}$ if $k\le1/h$ then $1+k^2h^2\le2$
$\text{(2d):}$ $H_n\ge\log(n+1)$
$\phantom{\text{(2d):}}$ i.e. $\frac1k\ge\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)$ and add
$\text{(2e):}$ $x\ge h$

For $-1\le x\lt0$, notice that $f'$ is even.

Therefore, $(2)$ says that
$$
\begin{align}
f'(0)
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x\tag{3a}\\
&=\infty\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$